# <a href=URL> opens like sitename.com/URL

Tags: php, html, links

I develops elementor widget.my a href code doesnt work like i want.the plugin works like that: admin set a url as text in elementor widget tab.and the text display as link for all equipment div:

```
   <div class="col-xs-12">


                        <div class="bag">

                            <?php $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

                            $html = wp_oembed_get($settings['url']);

                            echo '<a href="';

                            echo $settings['url'];

                            echo '">';

                            ?>



                                <div class="dot dot1">
                                    Ekipman
                                </div>
                            </a>
```

you can look at the working link:

http://www.migrate2.deniz-tasarim.site/homepage/

bottom of the link page there are box.you should click a box.then click right picture which is equipment **(dot1)** div.

when you click the equipment div, it opens:

http://www.migrate2.deniz-tasarim.site/homepage/sgdghd.com

however i want only sgdghd.com

Comment: And what does that $settings[‘url’] contain?

Comment: It sounds like you have only entered "sgdghd.com" as the URL, and that's not a valid link. Try entering "http://sgdghd.com" and see if that works without prepending.

Comment: Smoke detector doesn't like this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sgdghd.com` is not a complete URL on its own, and if used in a link like `<a href="sgdghd.com">`, it will be treated as a relative URL. To properly link to a different domain, you need to include `http://` or `https://`.

To ensure that a value for `href` is a valid URL, you should use `esc_url()` when outputting it. That way if a user enters an incomplete URL in the settings, it will still be output correctly:

```
echo '<a href="';

echo esc_url( $settings['url'] );

echo '">';
```

Comment: thanks, it works.can you vote my question?